# Why is vis.js not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I am trying vis.js and have been using the example which can be found here:
http://visjs.org/docs/network/

I used exact the same html-setup which is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/vis.js"></script>
    <link href="../../dist/vis.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">
        #mynetwork {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid lightgray;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // create an array with nodes
    var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
        {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
        {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
        {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
        {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
        {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
    ]);

    // create an array with edges
    var edges = new vis.DataSet([
        {from: 1, to: 3},
        {from: 1, to: 2},
        {from: 2, to: 4},
        {from: 2, to: 5}
    ]);

    // create a network
    var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');

    // provide the data in the vis format
    var data = {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges
    };
    var options = {};

    // initialize your network!
    var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript and Css are present.
When testing the file in Firefox or Chrome no Graphics nothing is happening. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/vis.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/vis.min.js"></script>
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Save my evening, sir! Going to buy some beer