# Syntax error in vis.js not detected when loading from remote site. Detected with local copy

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I wish to run the vis.js example http://visjs.org/examples/network/basicUsage.html by downloading the HTML on my machine, and also installing locally the vis.js files.
This remote URL runs without any error in Firefox.

When running it locally, the example does not run (No visible display) and I get the Firefox error message in the F12 debugger window:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical vis.js:3386:51
```

Indeed, there is missing right parenthesis in vis.js at this line:

```
// TODO: Remove "ordinalParse" fallback in next major release.
this._dayOfMonthOrdinalParseLenient = new RegExp(
    (this._dayOfMonthOrdinalParse.source || this._ordinalParse.source) +
        '|' + (/\d{1,2}/).source);
```

The example works by replacing vis.js by vis.min.js as suggested here: [Why is vis.js not displaying anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282203/why-is-vis-js-not-displaying-anything) but this does not explain why the syntax error is not detected when remote.

My question is: Why is this Javascript syntax error not detected when running the remote URL ?

Comment: somehow the copy you have has a bug. Download it again and resave it.

Comment: Same bug in online content: http://visjs.org/dist/vis.js . Look for "TODO: Remove"

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and it turned out that the date format in my data was incorrect.  The error is misleading as there actually isn't a missing parenthetical, but it is failing to parse the date correctly.  Be sure to use a date format of

```
start:'2017-04-19'
```

or

```
start:'2017-04-19 14:00:00'
```

in your data.  I was initially using the "number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970" timestamp, and that gave me the same error you have above.